# Writing to MongoDB using Spark/Scala throwing MongoTimeoutException

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I'm running below code for writing to MongoDB but it's failing with "com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[]".

spark-shell --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:1.1.0

```
    import org.bson.Document 
    import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark 
    import com.mongodb.spark.config.WriteConfig

    import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

    val uri  = s"mongodb://${user}:${pwd}@${host}/${db}?replicaSet=${replset}&authSource=${db}"

    val writeConfig: WriteConfig =  WriteConfig(Map("uri"->uri, "database"->db,  "collection"->collection, "replicaSet"->replset,   "writeConcern.w"->"majority"))

    val recs: List[String] = List(
    """{"a": 123, "b": 456, "c": "apple"}""",
    """{"a": 345, "b":  72, "c": "banana"}""",
    """{"a": 456, "b": 754, "c": "cat"}""",
    """{"a": 876, "b":  43, "c": "donut"}""",
    """{"a": 432, "b": 234, "c": "existential"}"""
    )

    val rdd_json_str: RDD[String] = sc.parallelize(recs, 5)
    val rdd_hex_bson: RDD[Document] = rdd_json_str.map(json_str =>  Document.parse(json_str))

    MongoSpark.save(rdd_hex_bson, writeConfig)
```

Please help me in resolving this.

Comment: That looks like it totally failed to connect to any MongoDB nodes.  What is the value of `uri` once everything gets interpolated?

Comment: Here is URI           uri: String = mongodb://testuser:testpwd@hostmongo.net:1234/admin?replicaSet=PSSSA&authSource=admin

Comment: I changed uri to connect to right nodes and replica set.Issue got resolved now!